# Thoughts on 2 CTAs in a hero/header section

Tags: homepage, call-to-action, landing-page, user-expectation, user-engagement

Premise:
I'm working on a landing page for a software company. Currently, the company offers one enterprise product. Soon, a second "lite" product will roll out, and I'm wondering about the hero/CTA.

I don't want to pull attention (read: paying clients) away from the first enterprise product, but I do want to highlight the new lite product.

Best practices say that I should have one CTA attached to the hero that will probably point to a product comparison page (with differences/pricing listed). However, I am toying with the idea of having two CTAs in the hero: one pointing to the product comparison page, and the other immediately launches the sign-up form for the new lite product.

Positives:
 + I remove a step in the signing up process (users launch the form from the landing page)
 + I maintain an easy way to navigate to the product comparison page.

Negatives:
 - I may confuse users with two CTAs
 - I may lose potential customers if they are confused by multiple choices in the decision tree. (click or not click vs click a, click b, or not click either)

Thoughts? Success rates? Should I just test each scenario?

I've found [one article on Smashing Magazine from 2009](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/13/call-to-action-buttons-examples-and-best-practices/) discussing two CTAs. But that's it. Do you have any good examples or strong opinions?

Comment: Does the user have every single piece of information they need on the hero to desire a sign-up form immediately? Getting them there is only half the battle. You also need them ready to convert to a customer, and forms aren't the best sales pitch.

Comment: I just whiteboarded it, and you're right @Zak. I just came to the same conclusion. Sometimes things are better in one's mind than when actually sketched out. :)

But to counter that, we have a lot of customers who investigate the product, then come back later to sign up/contact us. Also, in our industry, most of our potential customers are familiar with our software/offerings, but haven't used us because their businesses are too small to justify the costs. Either way though, throwing a, "TRY THE LITE!" isn't the best solution.

There's some cult joke in there, but I'm too tired to be witty. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is to not have 2 CTAs in 1 hero/header section.

You've already demonstrated the targeted users for these offerings and it sounds like they should each be given their due.

1. **Standard:** (remove references to 'Lite' - it should be a value add offering on its own)

With references to Ease of entry to your software, straight-forward to get started and reap immediate benefits.

1. **Comprehensive/Enterprise:**

For power users, and advanced teams etc.

Thoughts on how to make them both heroes are:

- Carousel the two hero elements with the carousel indicator at the top like tab menu items/pills
- Split up the Hero page with them both which with adequate negative space can present side by side. see. http://www.apprentice.io/tracks or https://www.mapdiva.com/